# how to create 2 content panels in north widget

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt

can we create 2 content panels in north widget.

```
BorderLayoutContainer con = new BorderLayoutContainer();
ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
VerticalLayoutContainer logoLayout = new VerticalLayoutContainer();
BorderLayoutData d = new BorderLayoutData(.20);
d.setMargins(new Margins());
Image logo = new Image("/IMAGES/Logo.png");
logoLayout.add(logo);
cp.add(logoLayout);
cp.setHeaderVisible(false);
con.setNorthWidget(cp, d);
```

please suggest me how to create two content panels.

Basically what I need to do is - please look into the image and let me know what I can do for that

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create your two panels within a single panel, and then assign that single panel to NORTH. Remember that your overall layout can be created from nested layouts.

```
ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
JPanel panelA = new JPanel();
JPanel panelB = new JPanel();
JPanel panelBig = new JPanel();

panelBig.add(panelA);
panelBig.add(panelB);
cp.add(panelBig, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

I think you can probably work out the rest of the details on your own.

Comment: can you please explain it in coding. I am newbie for it